# finding the conjunctive normal form of a statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I am currently trying to find the conjunctive normal form of this statement

$(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$.

I think I have found the answer but I am unsure if it is correct.

Am I correct in saying the answer is:

$A \lor B \lor \lnot C$

Comment: Seems right to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A \lor B \lor \lnot C$ is a conjunctive normal form (CNF) of $(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$.

A way to prove it is just to observe that $A \lor B \lor \lnot C$ is a CNF and it is logically equivalent (you can check it by means of truth tables) to $(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$.

An alternative proof is to use [logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) as rewriting rules leading from $(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$ to $A \lor B \lor \lnot C$. More precisely, observe first that:

\begin{align}
 ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B &\equiv (\lnot C \lor A \lor B) \land (\lnot B \lor B) &&\text{distributivity law} \\
&\equiv \lnot C \lor A \lor B &&\text{identity law (as $\lnot B \lor B$ is a tautology).}
\end{align}

Then (the use of the associativity law below is always implicit),
\begin{align}
 (A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B &\equiv (A \land B) \lor (\lnot C \lor A \lor B) &&\text{substitution} \\ 
& \equiv (A \land B) \lor (A \lor B) \lor \lnot C  &&\text{Associative law} \\
&\equiv ((A \lor A \lor B) \land (B \lor A \lor B)) \lor \lnot C && \text{distributivity law} \\
&\equiv ((A \lor B) \land (A \lor B)) \lor \lnot C && \text{idempotent law} \\
&\equiv A \lor B \lor \lnot C &&\text{idempotent law.}
\end{align}

Comment: would the DNF be the same?

Comment: @user10168997 - Yes, of course. In this case, your starting formula $(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$ has a CNF and a DNF that coincide.

Comment: @user10168997 - Pay attention that a CNF of a given formula is not unique, and similarly for DNF. For instance,  $A \land (A \lor B \lor \lnot C)$ is a CNF of $(A \land B) \lor ((\lnot C \lor A) \land \lnot B) \lor B$ as well. So, properly speaking it is not clear what you refer to when you talk of _the_ CNF of a given formula.